# Click checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, checkbox

I'm building html dynamically with Ajax.

This code generates my table:

```
$(".row-info").append(`
    <div class="items_container ${value}" id="${value}">
        <div class="col-md-2 item_ref">${value}</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 item_description">${response[0].nombre}</div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" style="width: 100%; text-align:center" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x text-danger remove_line" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></div>
    </div>
`);

$(".remove_line").on("click", function () {
    $(".items_container." + value).remove();
    $("." + value).click();
});
```

[image]

This image it's result for my table created dynamically. I have a red trash image that if clicked it removes a line from the table.

I need to do that when I click remove checkbox checked, but when I clicked in this checkbox, change message.

I tried with: `$('.'+value).click();` but my problem is that duplicate my entry in my table, always I can show my item selected. My message change, because detect when it's checked or not. But never remove my table line.

I don't know if have better solution to do this. And solve my problem.

**Resume:** when i click in checkbox "OFERTA" in left window, create iframe in right. When i check one checkbox in Iframes right I need create table resume in bottom.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my english.

Comment: `$(".remove_line").on('click'` is selecting every single item on the page with that class, not the one you just added.

Comment: `$(".remove_line").on('click', function(){ $(this).closest('.items_container').remove(); });`

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your responses, how i can uncheck my checkbox from right and change my message

Comment: @epascarello i´m using your your code and it´s ok, delete my line, but i need that uncheck checkbox but when uncheck this checkbox change my message, for example "should select another item..."

Comment: i solve my problem. update my question with my solution

Comment: Thanks, but answers go in the "answer" field, even if they're by the OP. Please remove the answer from the question and add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
$(".remove_line_"+value).on('click', function(){
                                        $(this).closest('.items_container').remove();    
                                        if($("."+value).prop('checked', true)){
                                            $("."+value).click();
                                            $("."+value).prop('checked', false);
                                        }
                                    });
```